# Using JDK17 & Record in Android Studio (Java, Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-17, java-record

[image]

### Part 1 :-

After getting this version of Android Studio, I am able to use **JDK17** in my project.
Everything works great, no build fails, no runtime error, etc.
(like enhanced-switch is working fine)
....but this warning keeps coming during each build. Is there any way to **suppress** this?

[image]
(Warning Text -> **"One or more classes has file version >= 56 which is not officially supported"**)

These are the build.gradle files:

(1):-

```
buildscript {

   repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-rc01'
       classpath 'com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.2.2'

       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

(2):-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.android.gms.strict-version-matcher-plugin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Sujal_Industries.SelfEmot"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.3.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:image-labeling:17.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.1.3'
}
```

(I tried searching for similar warnings but no luck)

### Part 2 :-

Recently, I found that Android Studio is now showing the option to create a new Java **Record**.
[image]

But when I create one and build the project, this error pops up:
[image]

So.. is there any way to forcefully add that **Record** class in java.lang package?

*(If any more information/clarification is needed on this, please let me know)*

**Edit**: I am aware of the fact that versions above 11 aren't **officially** supported but isn't there a workaround?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? Since I upgraded to the latest Android Studio I started getting this error.  If you did solve the issue could you please share the fix?

Comment: @LilMoke Try changing the Java Version to 11 and see if any settings are referring to higher versions than that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Android 14 SDK I can attest that all of the Java 17 language features below works flawlessly in a running app, neat! Code autocompletion and inspection also works for me.

- JEP 361: Switch Expressions
- JEP 378: Text Blocks
- JEP 394: Pattern Matching for instanceof
- JEP 395: **Records**
- JEP 409: Sealed Classes

[Here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/summary) they write:

> Android 14 includes features and improvements that further align with the OpenJDK 17 LTS release, including both library updates and Java 17 language support for app and platform developers.

I only get a Build warning saying that my Android Gradle plugin (8.0.2) hasn't been "tested with compileSdk = 34". If you were to update Android Studio to the Beta or Canary channels with newer Android Gradle plugins, I'm sure the warning would disappear. I'm using the current official version:

[image]

To start using Java 17 language goodies, [set up the Android 14 SDK](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/setup-sdk):

[image]

[image]

And in your app's build.gradle (using Groovy):

```
android {
    compileSdk 34
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

**For Part One:**
The Warning means that you have one or more classes within your project which are not supported for Java Versions higher than 11.

There are some dependencies which your project which are not compiled for JDK 17. That's because Android currently has no support for Java 17.
This means you are mixing up different Versions of Java Bitcode which produces this warning.

[Java Version Numbers](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion#1-java-version-numbers)

**For Part Two:**
You are trying to use a record, which is currently not supported in Android.

**Summary:**
You have set the Java Version for your Project to Java 17, which is currently not supported:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

The highest you can currently go is [Java 11](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?utm_source=android-studio-2020-3-1&utm_medium=studio-assistant-stable#java-11)
which means you have to change the compileOptions to:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

Comment: But how things like enhanced-switch working fine?

Comment: Don't know, maybe they have started some development for higher versions or they have implemented this feature for the Android SDK. The highest official supported Java Version is 11

Comment: The enhanced switch (without the pattern matching preview feature) does not require any bytecode support. Once compiled, the bytecode would work in all Java versions, as long as they don’t stumble over other features used in the same class.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of java bytecode supported by Android is Java 7

Android SDK supports desugaring for some of the later java features - https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.
These features are "syntactic sugar" - when light and short code constructions replace complex constructions to improve readability. Such features do not require significant changes in the JVM, and can be recompiled into previous versions of java bytecode

"Desugaring" means that source code from java 8 (or later) is compiled into bytecode of java 7 when it is possible

Most of Java8+ features are unsupported

If you want to write code for Android in a modern manner you have to switch to Kotlin

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use Java Record in Android. See
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197081367

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content.](/help/referencing).