# cannot access Record in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, java-17

I am getting error: cannot access Record
class file for java.lang.Record not found

I have configured JDK 17 and able to use other JDK 17 features like enhanced switch, triple quotes (""")
[image]

Please help on this.

There is no error while writing code but error is occurring on build.
[image]

Comment: Is that [part of the roster of supported JDK 8+ classes](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)?

Comment: It is not mentioned neither enhanced switch but switch is working. And Android Studio is not giving any error during writing code but error is coming on build.

Comment: "neither enhanced switch but switch is working" -- `switch` is not a Java class. The `record` keyword apparently requires `java.lang.Record`, which is not part of the de-sugared classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to update your build version to 34.
**Ref:** [Using JDK17 & Record in Android Studio (Java, Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70784107/using-jdk17-record-in-android-studio-java-android)